# Import Range, get all data IF column C matches several values

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The code below is my current code that works fine. It lets me import all data from one spreadsheet tab to another spreadsheet giving me the full range A:J. But now I do not want all data to be imported but I want to filter out specific stores (in sales data) based on their id number. The ID numbers are located in **column C** in source spreadsheet. I want to Filter for **8 different values in column C** and import all data matching that condition into the targeted spreadsheet.

```
function importhistorical_sales_ee() {
  //geth  values to be imported from the source sheet
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1mVECYu27lnOIFf7vHk1kI_55DID3APvWr_toWuZho14').
  getSheetByName('Historical sales for SC planning -.csv').getRange('A:J').getValues();
  
  //set  values imported   
   var target = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('test_ee');
   target.getRange("A3:J").clearContent();
   target.getRange(3,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

I tested several options like the one below (but it is not working). I am expecting to be able to set the column I want to filter on and then also set which values I want to look for in that column.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example.

I have sample data in a spreadsheet like this.

[image]

I then filter the data for an array of 3 values as shown in the script.  You can make it 8 or whatever you want.  I prefer to use `getDataRange()` but you could use `getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),9).getValues()`.  This ensures your not getting a bunch of blank rows.

**Code.gs**

```
function filterStores () {
  try {
    let wanted = [1,3,5];
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let stores = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),9).getValues();
    let filtered = stores.filter( store => {
        return wanted.some( id => store[2] === id );
      }
    );

    let target = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('test_ee');
    target.getRange(3,1,target.getLastRow()-2,9).clearContent();
    target.getRange(3,1,filtered.length,filtered[0].length).setValues(filtered);
    console.log(filtered);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Execution log**

```
9:16:03 AM  Notice  Execution started
9:16:05 AM  Info    [ [ 'a1', 'b1', 1, 'd1', 'e1', '', 'g1', '', '', 'j1' ],
  [ 'a3', 'b3', 3, 'd3', 'e3', '', 'g3', '', '', 'j3' ],
  [ 'a5', 'b5', 5, 'd5', 'e5', '', 'g5', '', '', 'j5' ],
  [ 'a3', 'b3', 3, 'd3', 'e3', '', 'g3', '', '', 'j3' ] ]
9:16:05 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

**References**

- [Array.filtere()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)
- [Array.some()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_some.asp)
- [Arrow function](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp)

Comment: It did not work. Can you explain what your 'return wanted.some' means? And why [2]? I ran the code but it only gave me all data and did not filter out those 8 values I choose from column C. let stores = sheet.getDataRange("C").getValues(); // as you see I added "C" column there - is this wrong?

Comment: 1st there is no parameter to `getDataRange()`.  That method of Sheet returns the values in the range from cell A1 to the last column with a value and the last row with a value.  So there are no empty rows.  2nd `Array.some()` searches through an Array and returns true for the first match.  By returning true or false to the enclosing `Array.filter()`  that row will be stored in the filter Array.  3rd `stores` is a 2D array.  The `Array.filter()` takes each row of the `stores` array and passes a row `store` to `Array.some()`.  So `store[2]` is the same as column C.

Comment: and do I still keep or remove the original function that gives me all data? Since in your function where does it know the target spreadsheet and gsheetname? Thanks btw for the help!

Comment: Also in your examples you are writing 'store' and 'stores' often - is this doing anything to the code or do I need to rename it? The column C header is 'Provider ID', basically store id.

Comment: I've editted my script to write to your target sheet and to getRange() only A thru J.  I don't understand your second question.  I've shown my data sheet and the execution log shows it is working so other than what I've added to the script it works as is.